# replace a-hats in GCC output with more meaningful text

Tags: c, gcc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does gcc have “â” in all its error messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547071/why-does-gcc-have-a-in-all-its-error-messages)

New to C programming, and I'm using GCC. I'm noticing a lot of "a-hat" outputs from GCC, and I'm starting to feel like I could miss some important information if this continues. For example:

```
/usr/include/gconv.h:72: error: expected declaration specifiers or â before â
/usr/include/gconv.h:174: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before â
/usr/include/libio.h:486: error: expected â, â, â, â or â before â
/usr/include/stdio.h:308: error: expected declaration specifiers or â before â
/usr/include/stdio.h:610: error: expected â, â, â, â or â before â
DATA_a.txt: In function â:
DATA_a.txt:3: error: expected expression before â token
DATA_a.txt:3: error: â undeclared (first use in this function)
Txvalues.c:11: error: expected expression before â token
```

Anyone know why I'm seeing these a-hats, and how to replace them with something more meaningful? I'm not interested in fixing the bugs in the program (I created them on purpose to show lots of errors with a-hats). But since all bugs show these a-hats (real or created), I want to know how to setup GCC to replace these a-hats with meaningful information.

Comment: You are sure those are produced by `gdb` and not `gcc`? This looks like compiler output and `gdb` is not a compiler.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. I'll update question.

Comment: pmg, that worked for me. If you place as answer I'll accept. thanks!

Comment: @ggkmath: The point of marking questions as duplicates is to avoid duplicating all the answers too. You can voice your support by upvoting the answer on the other question.

Comment: Sorry Jefromi, the duplicate question didn't come up in my searches since I searched on a-hat rather than â. Their answer works for me as well, although pmg's answer here, which also works for me, doesn't appear in the duplicate posting. Would be happy to delete this posting if recommended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think they're [Unicode quotes](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html).

Using

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

before compiling gets rid of the "a-hats" for me.

Attention: I don't know what implications (if any) this has. Use at your own risk.

Answer (score 2):

At a wild guess, you're not using a terminal that supports extended characters. Most modern terminal types should support unicode, and therefore should present the error messages in a form that is legible. What terminal type are you using?

Comment: Hmm, that might be it. I'm using X11.app on a Mac (Snow Leopard) to ssh tunnel into remote server. The Preferences settings for X11 don't show any way to enable unicode support. There must be some other way to enable them.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you `#include`-d a raw text file (e.g. your `DATA_a.txt`) which does not contain valid C syntax. Or perhaps some comment has not been closed with `*/`. A lexical error in a file might spill to some next `#include`-d file.

To understand what is the source like (for the compiler) after preprocessing, you could use e.g.

```
 gcc -C -E yourcode.c > yourcode.i
```

(on a Linux machine) and then look inside `yourcode.i`

Comment: Correct, I'm using // here instead of /* and */ for comments to generate these a-hats, and compiled the file with -ansi switch, which doesn't allow the // style comments. However, seems like any other general error contains these a-hats as well. Not trying to fix the errors here, just try to understand why they all contain this code rather than the actual text.

Comment: You should read a good C programming book, and try to "think at the place of the compiler".

Comment: Thanks for the line of code above. Additional info always good during debugging. I've been reading Prata's C Primer Plus, and it's been invaluable.